# Android FATAL EXCEPTION: main?

Tags: android, android-manifest

i have this code

```
package com.UPFIM.casa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Constancias extends Activity {


    public String nivels;
    public String tipos;

    public String cant;
    public String fot;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.constancias);

            EditText nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
     EditText matricula = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edusuario);
     EditText mensaje;
     EditText subje;


            final String nivel[]=new String[]{"Nivel","Preparatoria","Profesional"};
            final String tipoc[]=new String[]{"Tipo de Constancia",
                    "Inscripción en el Periodo en Curso",
                    "Inscripción en el Periodo Inmediato Anterior",
                    "Inscripción con Periodo Vacacional",
                    "Servicio Militar Nacional",
                    "Inscripción con Promedio Acumulado",
                    "Inscripción con Promedio del Periodo Inmediato Anterior",
                    "Inscripción en el Periodo en Curso con Materias Inscritas",
                    "Inscripción en el Periodo Inmediato Anterior con Materias",
                    "Inscripción con Promedio del Periodo Inmediato Anterior y Promedio Acumulado",
                    "Inscripción en el Periodo en Curso con Materias Inscritas y Calificaciones",
                    "Inscripción en el Periodo Inmediato Anterior con Materias que se Cursaron y Calificaciones",
                    "Inscripción en el Periodo de Verano",
                    "Documentación en Trámite de Legalización",
                    "Documentación en trámite de Apostille",
                    "Terminación de Estudios",
                    "Terminación de Estudios con Promedio",
                    "Carta de Buena Conducta",
                    "Nivel de Ingles",
                    "Beca"};

            final String[] cantidad = new String[]{"1->$20.00","2->$40.00","3->$60.00","4->$80.00","5->$100.00"};
            final String[] foto = new String[]{"Si","No"};








     final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
     final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
     final Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
     final Spinner spinner4 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nivel);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                android.view.View v, int position, long id) {
                nivels = new String("\nNivel: " + nivel[position]);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                nivels = new String("");
            }
    });


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tipoc);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter1);

    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter1);

    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(
        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                android.view.View v, int position1, long id) {
                tipos = new String("\nTipo: " + tipoc[position1]);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                tipos = new String("");
            }
    });



    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cantidad);
    spinner3.setAdapter(adapter2);

    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner3.setAdapter(adapter2);

    spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(
        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                android.view.View v, int position2, long id) {
                cant = new String("\nCantidad: " + cantidad[position2]);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                cant = new String("");
            }
    });


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, foto);
    spinner4.setAdapter(adapter3);

    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner4.setAdapter(adapter3);

    spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(
        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                android.view.View v, int position3, long id) {
                fot = new String("\nFoto: " + foto[position3]);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                fot = new String("");
            }
    });



    mensaje.setText("" + nombre.getText().toString() + "\n" + matricula.getText().toString() + nivels + tipos + cant + fot );
    subje.setText("Solicitud de Constancia APP");

     }

     public void enviarme (View view){
         Intent itSend = new Intent( android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

         itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"spartan-004@hotmail.com"});
         itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subje.getText());
         itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mensaje.getText());

         startActivity(itSend);

     }



}
```

But i don't found my error because i see this log

```
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.UPFIM.casa/com.UPFIM.casa.Constancias}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
03-18 19:26:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at com.UPFIM.casa.Constancias.<init>(Constancias.java:22)
```

here is the layout:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
`android:orientation="vertical"`
`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`
`android:layout_height="fill_parent"`
`android:background="@drawable/fondo">`
`<ScrollView`
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tituloAbout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/constancias"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/vacio" 
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/nom" android:paddingLeft="10dip"/>

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"/>  


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="@string/Nivel" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="@string/tipo" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="@string/cant" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner3" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            /> 


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="@string/foto" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner4" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            /> 


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="@string/Advertencia" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/enviar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:onClick="enviarme" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
EditText nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
EditText matricula = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edusuario);
```

You are initialising EditTexts before their instances are added to Activity by

```
setContentView();
```

So this always will throw **`NPE`**.

**Solution:** Move these lines behind `setContentView()` and it will works.

```
setContentView(R.layout.constancias);
EditText nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
EditText matricula = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edusuario);
```

### Explanation:

Whenever you want to initialise your widgets with `findViewById()` at first must be called

```
setContentView(R.layout.layoutId)
```

because key purpose of `setContentView()` method is to create all instances of UI elements contained in layout you define and that will be set as content of Activity. So always if you will call `findViewById()` before `setContentView()` it always throws `NullPointerException` becauses Views are null.

Comment: @StockDave look at me answer. just move your two lines of EditText behind setContentView method.

Comment: i have the same problem, the applications has stopped

Comment: @StockDave add new logcat.

Comment: how u can se in the question edited, i moved the Edit Text, but now, more down i have other problem now
itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subje.getText()); itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mensaje.getText());

Comment: you didn't initialise your vaiables: `EditText mensaje;
     EditText subje;` you need to initialise them.

Comment: i don't have the answer, but i did, i initilise the variables
ÈditText mesaje = null` its correct?

Comment: i need help, please have me patient :( and excusame for my bad english

Comment: @StockDave man initialise all editboxes with findViewById() and then you can call getText() method.

Answer (score 1):

To get the view first you need to set layout of activity.

Move these lines inside the onCreate method.

```
EditText nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
EditText matricula = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edusuario);
```

like

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.constancias);

    EditText nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    EditText matricula = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edusuario);
   .....
 }
```

### EDIT:

You did not even initialize the

```
EditText mensaje;
EditText subje;
```

and here you setting the text.

Again here NPE

```
mensaje.setText("" + nombre.getText().toString() + "\n" + matricula.getText().toString() + nivels + tipos + cant + fot );
subje.setText("Solicitud de Constancia APP");
```

So initialize these also in `onCreate` method as I initialized above.

Comment: @StockDave Post the logcat now here

Comment: the error now is in this part:
`itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subje.getText());`
         `itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mensaje.getText());`
in subje and mensaje

Comment: @StockDave Please check my updated answer. I already told to you for this. Don't forgot to accept answer if its solve your problem.

Comment: sorry my friend i´m mexican, and i started learn android, but i don´t see te problem, i need more explain :(

Comment: @StockDave Post the layout fast.

Comment: @StockDave You xml is totally wrong you did not define and name of textview and please see android developer how to make layout. I will see it later.

Comment: not yet, i change all the editText for Strings, but i have null in the mensagge

Answer (score 0):

You might be working on 2 different project and mistakenly you could have copy google-services.json of one project to another project. It happen to me. Hope it helps

Your debug might have different google-services file where as release might have another.. same for IOS googleinfo.plist